# How to make a latex table

Tags: latex

There are two rows. The first with three texts (A, B and C) centered under the vertical line. The second with four cells and centralized text.

```
         A        B        C
|  text  |  text  |  text  |  text  |
```

Comment: What have you tried and what's the error?

Answer (score 3):

You can use some `\phantom`s in the header row and set the vertical line headers inside a `\makebox[2\tabcolsep]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | *{4}{c|} }
  \multicolumn{4}{ c }{%
    \phantom{textA}%
      \makebox[2\tabcolsep]{A}%
    \phantom{textAB}%
      \makebox[2\tabcolsep]{B}%
    \phantom{textABC}%
      \makebox[2\tabcolsep]{C}%
    \phantom{textABCD}
  } \\
  textA &
    textAB &
    textABC &
    textABCD
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```